# Why many web developers use java programming language for web development?

Tags: web-development

I know a lot of programming languages ​​that can be used to web development like PHP, ASP, etc. but why many web developers use java programming language for web development?

Comment: Because many developers use Java programming language for web development.  Seriously.  Nobody wants to be the guy who took a risk on some exotic language that no one knows.

Comment: Why would they not choose Java? If you go by a checklist of features offered (tools, libs, docs, workflow...), Java might well be the top choice, and you need some reason to *not* choose it, a reason for another choice (which there are many, of course).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't Java used for modern web application development?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/102090/why-isnt-java-used-for-modern-web-application-development) BWA-HA-HA that's a typical issue with questions like [Gorilla vs Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) - these look the same holywar no matter how you turn them

Comment: @gnat Strike “possible” from that; it's exactly that one again. It's like an undead question; strike it down and it rises from the grave once more!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java is "safe" for corporate managers.  I think it is less often you see startups without corporate managers choosing Java (sorry, no stats off hand), and more often you will see Java or .NET in large corporate environments.

Safe means several things, including the ability to hire talent.  Or that the other stuff is based on Java, so we need to stay with it.  Or that is what we learned in school.  Many reasons.

Few managers will get fired for choosing Java or .NET, but they may get fired if they choose Python or Ruby and it doesn't "work out".

I heard a developer I very much respect tell me once:

"Java allows mediocre developers to crank out mediocre software at a predictable pace"  -- And it makes sense!  There are endless docs to read, books to digest, and springs and beans to play with.

*(Note: observing from the sidelines here.  I almost adopted Java for web-development once... I was that fed up with PHP.  We ended up standardizing on Python 3, and could not be happier at this point.  But there was no "manual" to read -- we built our own infrastructure)*

Comment: Just like "nobody ever got fired for buying IBM".